# Getting the Dimensions of an LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 in Direct X 9.0c?

Tags: c++, directx

Does anyone know if there is a function in DirectX to get the dimensions of an LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9? I just need the width and height. If there isn't, anyone know of a quick and dirty way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE`'s may contain [multiple images of different sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap).  You'll have to specify which one you want. Usually, 0 is the original size, others are mipmaps that used for optimizing performance on GPU.

```
D3DSURFACE_DESC surfaceDesc;
int level = 0; //The level to get the width/height of (probably 0 if unsure)
myTexture->GetLevelDesc(level, &surfaceDesc); 
size_t size = surfaceDesc.Width * surfaceDesc.Height;
```